# Does Queue.get block main?

Tags: python

I know that `Queue.get()` method in python is a blocking function. I need to know if I implemented this function inside the main, waiting for an object set by a thread, does this means that all the main will be blocked.

For instance, if the main contains functions for transmitter and receiver, will the two work together or not?

Comment: Can you show some code?  Question is not clear (to me).

Answer (score 23):

Yes -- if you call `some_queue.get()` within either the thread or the `main` function, the program will block there until some object as passed through the queue.

---

However, it is possible to use queues so that they [don't block](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get), or so that they have a timeout of some kind:

```
import Queue

while True:
    try:
        data = some_queue.get(False)  
        # If `False`, the program is not blocked. `Queue.Empty` is thrown if 
        # the queue is empty
    except Queue.Empty:
        data = None

    try:
        data2 = some_queue.get(True, 3)  
        # Waits for 3 seconds, otherwise throws `Queue.Empty`
    except Queue.Empty:
        data = None
```

You can do the same for `some_queue.put` -- either do `some_queue.put(item, False)` for non-blocking queues, or `some_queue.put(item, True, 3)` for timeouts. If your queue has a size limit, it will throw a `Queue.Full` exception if there is no more room left to append a new item.

Comment: Just to clarify, the program will only block the thread that's calling the 'queue.get()' function, right?

Comment: Yep, `queue.get()` will block only a thread where it was called.

Comment: The term `block` could be a bit misleading here, or at least merits more depth. The line of code will wait alright, but it will not be blocking in the sense of hogging the processor (or any processor) nor will it hold the GIL I think. Rather, it will awaken asynchronously when something goes into the queue, which in some other contexts you'd call "non blocking".

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will block main/thread. if you want to get all messages without blocking try this

```
def get_messages(q):
    messages = []

    while q.qsize():
        messages.append(q.get())
        # or process message here

    return messages
```

If messages are like stream above code might get caught in loop.
to avoid that use "for loop" and get all the messages sent so far

```
def get_messages(q):
    messages = []

    for _ in range(q.qsize()):
        messages.append(q.get())
        # or process message here

    return messages
```